# Pearlescent level requirement

Tags: borderlands-2

Does anyone know the requirements for Pearscent rarity weapons in Borderlands 2? I am level 35 and don't have DLC. I'd love to know if I can get them earlier than level 50.

Answer (score 2):

In Borderlands 2, Pearlescents were introduced in Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack 1, and they exclusively drop in Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode difficulty.

So, unfortunately, no, you can't have them without DLC or before level 50.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at some of my characters from awhile back and my gaige has a lol 35 perlescwnt pistol. It think the drop rate is infinitesimal but it can occur

Comment: You must have gotten this from the slot machine in Dragon Keep, as per [this wiki page](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Pearlescent): "They can also be won from the slot machine in Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep, even in Normal Mode and True Vault Hunter Mode, making that slot machine the only source of Pearlescent weapons of level less than 50."